WSo2 Identity Server 7.0.0 claim update API exception
I'm getting this claim update API error for all the claims in Identity Server 7.0.0. Could you please help me to resolve the error.
{"code":"UE-10000","message":"Invalid Request.","description":"Provided request body content is not in the expected format.","traceId":"1bd479b7-173b-4e4a-b525-59230d42677c"}

This is a sample PUT API i tried, same exception gives for all the claims.
curl -X 'PUT' \

'https://localhost:9443/api/server/v1/claim-dialects/local/claims/aHR0cDovL3dzbzIub3JnL2NsYWltcy9pZGVudGl0eS9lbWFpbFZlcmlmaWVk' \

-H 'accept: */*' \

-H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \

-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \

-d '{"claimURI":"http://wso2.org/claims/identity/emailVerified","dialectURI":"http://wso2.org/claims","description":"Email Verified","displayOrder":0,"displayName":"Email Verified","readOnly":false,"regEx":"","required":false,"supportedByDefault":false,"attributeMapping":[{"mappedAttribute":"emailVerified","userstore":"PRIMARY"}],"properties":[]}' -k


The issue is having the  "dialectURI" in your PUT payload.
Remove the "dialectURI" from the payload and try it again. It should work.
Here is a sample CURL which is functioning properly:
curl --location --request PUT 'https://localhost:9443/api/server/v1/claim-dialects/local/claims/aHR0cDovL3dzbzIub3JnL2NsYWltcy9pZGVudGl0eS9lbWFpbFZlcmlmaWVk' \
--header 'accept: */*' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "claimURI": "http://wso2.org/claims/identity/emailVerified",
    "description": "Email Verified",
    "displayOrder": 0,
    "displayName": "Email Verified",
    "readOnly": false,
    "regEx": "",
    "required": false,
    "supportedByDefault": false,
    "attributeMapping": [
        {
            "mappedAttribute": "emailVerified",
            "userstore": "PRIMARY"
        }
    ],
    "properties": []
}'

Refer the PUT payload in API documentation:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/claim-management-rest-api/#tag/management/operation/updateLocalClaim
